# Match multiple optional characters in filename

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match variations in filenames using the following regex.  I am attempting to match *all* of the listed filenames.

`[IMG]{3}[0-9]{8}[_]?[a-zA-Z]?[0-9]{2}?\.JPG` [regexr example #1](http://regexr.com/3allv)

```
IMG20150114_V10.JPG (match)
IMG20150114V10.JPG (match)
IMG20150114_V.JPG
IMG20150114A.JPG
IMG20150114a.JPG
IMG20150114.JPG
```

This example matches the rest of the set:

`[IMG]{3}[0-9]{8}[_]?[a-zA-Z]?\.JPG`  [regexr example #2](http://regexr.com/3alm5)

```
IMG20150114_V10.JPG 
IMG20150114V10.JPG
IMG20150114_V.JPG (match)
IMG20150114A.JPG (match)
IMG20150114a.JPG (match)
IMG20150114.JPG (match)
```

What am I missing to match all of the filenames in the list with a single expression?

Comment: Can you show us some *negative* cases as well? Without knowing the rules one might be tempted to answer `/.*/`.

Comment: [0-9]{2} could be replace by [0-9]{0,2}

Comment: @Biffen, `IMG20150114_V100`, `IMG20150114_V_`, `IMG20150114_V!`, `IMG20150114_VXY`, `IMG20150114ABCD`,  are examples of negatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one should suit your needs:

```
IMG\d{8}(?:[a-zA-Z]|_?V\d*)?\.JPG
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2PPO3vdFoGxh9jhJ)

Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3alm8)

Comment: How would I allow for `IMG20150114A1.JPG`?

Comment: I modified yours to account for `IMG20150114A1.JPG` -->  `IMG\d{8}(?:[a-zA-Z][0-9]?|_?V\d*)?\.JPG`.   I guess I need to know how to add in the character counts with the optional flag (?).   Ex, how do I write `[0-9]{2}`?  (optionally allow 0-99)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
[IMG]{3}[0-9]{8}[_]?[a-zA-Z]?(?:[0-9]{2})?\.JPG
```

The last two digits are optional.

Take care that `[IMG]{3}` matches `III` or `GGI` ...  may be you want:

```
IMG[0-9]{8}_?[a-zA-Z]?(?:[0-9]{2})?\.JPG
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work

```
IMG\d+_?[a-zA-Z]*\d{0,2}.JPG
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX8xD4/3)

Comment: This is simple and clean but also validates `IMG20150114___A_10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.JPG`: http://regexr.com/3alme

Comment: validates: `IMG20150114_V10000000000000000000000000000000000.JPG`